# How to render entity id in views when showing entities not fields

Tags: views, 8, theming

How can I include the entity id in views output when rendering entities? I have a jQuery script that further processes each entity, but for doing so, I need to know the entity id. So I need to include it somehow in the rendered output. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In case of field display:

- an field "node_id" that takes node id value ( you can hide the output ).
- an field that can use "Rewrite the output of this field" with an output like: `<div class="entity_{{ nid }}">something</div>`

In case of entity display:

- override node--yourcontenttype–teaser.html.twig, and replace `{{ content }}`  with:  `<div class="entity_{{ entity.id.value }}">{{ content }}</div>`

Then you can use jquery to handle the div with respective class or id.

Comment: This works for showing fields, but I am using the whole entity in views, so that I can't add additional fields, at least I don't know how.

Comment: although this does not work for me as I use the entity (see above) how can I hide the output in your first suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, now i've seen that you want to show the whole entity. In this case you can use twig to style the display type of your entity. Use twig_field_value module to display the node_id inside your twig template.

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your needs, hope it helps